# Magento Change Price Issue

Tags: php, magento

In the view catalog page I have added a custom select drop down. On selection of an option  by the user the price should change accordingly. But as a option is chosen from the dropdown  I am getting this error

TypeError: opConfig is undefined..

I have searched for this opConfig problem in Magento but didn't find a solution..

Comment: I flushed magento cache and cleared the cookies from browser and this worked for me though I still didn't understood the problem..It has something to do with varien.js..

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause of this issue.

In your themes equivalent of this path

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options.phtml
```

You'll see an empty line before the line `Product.Options = Class.create();`. Remove this empty line and the opConfig issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not simple.
in your view page find this line ( options.phtml )

```
 var opConfig = new Product.Options(...);
```

but your page has undefined error so there has 2 reason,

1. javascript error in your product view page before opConfig.
2. config not completly script in page.